# This import is empty and if applied would delete all of your configurations

Tags: commerce, drush, installation-profiles

Customer bought a theme that has a Commerce plugin installed with sample data.
Anxious to get it running and try out the new configuration system, I did what I do prior to Drupal 8.6: I committed everything but sensitive info into git, cloned to my local, and dumped the MySQL database. After getting the index page, every page returned a 500 error like the following ones.

> Attempt to create a field commerce_remote_id that does not exist on entity type user

> The entity type does not exist. in `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager::getDefinition()`

Copying all files from modules/commerce to modules/profile should get me past these errors.

`drush updb` returns no updates needed. `drush cr` offers no relief.

OK, I wanted to start using the new configuration system. On the customer site, I ran `drush cex` and committed to git.

On my local, after `git pull`, `drush cim` returns:

> This import is empty and if applied would delete all of your configuration, so has been rejected.

It appears that Drush will not import, but I prefer to use `drush site:install` with an existing configuration.

Can Drush 9.5.2 install a new site onto itself using the existing settings.php file?

I would like to synchronize configuration files to remove that as a factor to resolve my local site being hosed.

I read in another tutorial that the UUID must be copied over because the UUIDs in system.site.yml must match. I can confirm they match by running `drush config.get system.site`.

Comment: Is it configured to point at the right config directory so Drush knows where to look for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do double check the directory where the config files are located. The directory is set in settings.php like:

```
$config_directories['sync'] = 'sites/default/files/[...]/sync';
```

I had the same issue but moving the `config` directory to the correct place solved it.

Comment: do the export to that folder first, then cim works properly drush cex sync